# How to resolve problem in pip installing Selenium in python 3.6.1

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to install Selenium in python 3.6.1 through pip install,I was prompted with error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium".

Comment: Which operating system are you on, do you have other python binaries and how did you install python 3.6 on the machine?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.I don't have any binaries and i installed from official website.